# how set password for password odoo secret in file?

Tags: docker, odoo

i run container postgres and odoo container in linux system by docker, the problem is how to set password for odoo secret like in postgres :

```
$ echo 'secret' > notpasswords

$ docker run -d --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/notpasswords -v "$PWD/notpasswords:/notpasswords" postgres:9.6-alpine

$ docker run -it --rm --link pg postgres:9.6 bash
root@c37d1f3f2910:/# psql -h pg -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (9.6.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning to use this in a production environment, you should take a look at [docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#docker-secrets). In this case, you can make use of a special postgres environment variable to refer to the postgres password (POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE).

```
$ docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgres-passwd -d postgres
```